# The position of my document is negative of my margin (Margin 100, Position -100)

Tags: html, css

I've got html for a table and I'm trying to center it

```
<table class="something">
    <tr>
        <td>words</td>
        <td>words2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS

```
table {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

When looking at the dev tools it says,
left position : -775 and left margin : 775.
right position : 775 and right margin : 775

The right side is as I expect but I can't seem to figure out why the left side is acting the way it does. If I modify the margin and position in the dev tools so its all 775 then it does what I'm expecting. Should I be using some other method for centering this?

In my HTML I do have a 2 other div elements that are above this table and one below.

Comment: can you share more code? It's hard to debug like that

Comment: @HassenCh. Yeah this is all of my css 


In the post

Comment: Why position absolute on the table?

Comment: @Phix From my understanding of css, since the table doesn't have any other parents I think its supposed to use the document as the parent and align itself based on it. So I thought this would be the best way to align it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Write these codes in your css file.**

```
table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks that worked! I guess I'll have to look at what transform does. Is there anything you can tell me about why top and left by themselves wouldn't work?